# Why is my SSD WEI score decreasing rapidly?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-experience-index

My 120 gig SSD started out as 7.5 when it was fresh (windows was installed on it), and after a week or so it decreased to a 7.3. Two months later, it's now at 6.9. I think TRIM is turned on after I ran this check in cmd:

```
fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

The result came out as 0. I have 32.5 gb free space in the SSD. I ran a disk error check and nothing came up.

Computer specs:

- Intel i7 980x processor
- Win7 Pro 64 bit OS
- 12 gig tri channel RAM
- GTX 580 graphics
- C:\ - 120 (windows says 112) gig SSD
- E:\ - 1 tb HDD

I also noticed I have a random disk, 'Q:\'. It has 0 bytes max space, and it wasn't there when I last checked (a month ago?). I have absolutely no idea how it got here...

**EDIT: I've found that my SSD (OCZ Agility) does have TRIM support, but I have no idea if this runs automatically or how to use it, I really have no experience with SSDs whatsoever. Could anyone help with this?**

Comment: What's the SSD model?  Also, FWIW, that command just shows if TRIM is supported by your OS configuration, it doesn't necessarily mean it's getting done.

Comment: Oh - how can I check if TRIM is getting done?

Comment: Does the drive have a manual TRIM utility?  (Again, what model is it?)

Comment: I've no idea whether it has a trim util, but the model is according to the properties: OCZ-AGILITY3 ATA. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with OCZ drives to say what would work - I don't see a utility on their website. :/

Comment: See edit, I have no idea how to actually use trim if it doesn't run automatically

Comment: The Q drive could be from "Microsoft CLick to Run"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've found that my SSD (OCZ Agility) does have TRIM support, but I
>   have no idea if this runs automatically or how to use it, I really
>   have no experience with SSDs whatsoever. Could anyone help with this?

To verify TRIM commands are being passed you do this.

> fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
>
> The result came out as 0. I have 32.5 gb free space in the SSD. I ran
>   a disk error check and nothing came up.

Which you've already verified as 0, thus Windows is passing TRIM commands to your drive (technically it is being passed to the motherboard, but never the less.)

No idea what this **Q** drive is. Dismount it and see what happens.

I never trust the WEI. Get a real benchmark like [AS SSD](http://downloads.guru3d.com/AS-SSD-Benchmark-download-2569.html) to verify your results.